# Info From plist in UITableViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios

I have a plist that I am trying to pull data from to display in a UITableViewController that is acting as a DetailViewController. I know how to display data from a plist in a UIPickerView. Is it the same, or what changes should be made?

What I have is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{

    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSBundle*bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Grammar" ofType:@"plist"];
    grammarArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];

    [self configureView];
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewdidSelectRow:(NSInteger)rowinComponent:(NSInteger)component
{

}
```

Where do I go from here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's pretty straight forward:

To be able to show data in a `UITableViewCell` is done by using the `UITableViewController`'s

`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` delegate method.

Inside this method you can set the various members of the current [`UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Such as `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel`.

[You can further extend a `UITableViewCell` and add more features to it.](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html)

Comment: Well, what I need to do is pull data from my PLIST. If I were using a UIPickerView, I'd do something like:

"
- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
"

Then I would do my NSDictionary and NSStrings from my PLIST so I could use what I chose from the UIPickerView in my labels. How do I do something similar with UITableViews?

Comment: in a UITableViewController you've got a similar method called `cellForRowAtIndexPath` use that to initialize your cells

Comment: I get an error using the "row" where it says "row" is not defined. 

What would I use? The full code looks like

`- (void)viewDidLoad
{    
    NSBundle*bundle=[NSBundle mainBundle];
    NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"Grammar" ofType:@"plist"];
    grammarArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
    
    [self configureView]
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSDictionary *grammarInfo = [grammarArray cellForRowAtIndexPath:row];
}`

Comment: can you post your code on https://gist.github.com/ or update your question? makes it easier to track bugs

Comment: I think you should have a look at the iOS TableView programming guide
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html